How could I filter APM events on sentry for ASP.NET?
In my ASP.NET app, we are using sentry to log errors, but we want to filter all the APM messages.
I was intending to filter it using the following approaches:
options.SetBeforeSendTransaction((sentryTransaction, hint) =>
{ 
    if (sentryTransaction // somehow look here if it's APM related)
    {
        return null; // Drop the transaction by returning null
    }

    return sentryTransaction;
});

or
options.SetBeforeSend((sentryEvent, hint) =>
{
    if (sentryEvent //somehow look here if it's APM related) )
    {
        return null; // Don't send this event to Sentry
    }

    sentryEvent.ServerName = null; // Never send Server Name to Sentry
    return sentryEvent;
});

Problem is I couldn't find a way to check if it's apm.
I would look for event type and check if it's a transaction, but IDK if it's enough, and the sentryEvent doesn't contain a type property.
Can someone help me find a way? Thanks

What do you mean by "APM Message'? You can turn off transaction by setting TracesSampleRate to 0

@BrunoGarcia I mean filtering all messages related to Performance Monitoring... if I set it to 0 it would do the trick?

Yeah, it would stop sending transactions altogether. Transactions are used to measure performance.

I ended filtering it by the logger tag
builder.AddSentry(options => {
    options.SetBeforeSend((sentryEvent, hint) =>
    {
            if (sentryEvent.Logger == "Elastic.Apm")
            {
                    return null;
            }
            return sentryEvent;
    });
});


You can set options.TracesSampleRate = 0
or don't set this value at all since default is 0
Make sure EnableTracing is also set to false. Not a great name for the option but it in essence enables performance monitoring too.
